# Replace an empty space in a string with value "N/A" -Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to replace a string having any empty spaces with the value "N/A". Example:
I have an array;

```
var array= ["value1", undefined, "value3"];
var array2= ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
var array3= ["value1", "value2", undefined];
```

this is a dynamic generated array and hence the values can differ. I have 3 instances of array with different values in populated in it. now I want to remove all the `undefined` values from array and replace it with say - "N/A";
First I converted array into string and then did replace.

```
array.toString().replace(/\:''/gi, "\:\"\""); 
outputs: "value1,,value3"; instead I want:  "value1, N/A, value3"
```

however im not well versed with regex and hence im failing at this.

any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex, use `.map` instead:

```js
var array= ["value1", undefined, "value3"];
const newArr = array.map(item => item === undefined ? 'N/A' : item);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexp, you can use map or your own implementation, this case use:

```
for(let it in array) if(array[it] == undefined || array[it] == "") array[it] = "N/A";
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of map because replacing occurs in place.

```js
var array = ["value1", undefined, "value3"];

array.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element === undefined) {
        array[index] = "N/A";
    }
});

console.log(array);
```